Introducing of ⟹ in Isabelle Pure proof
I'd like to build a Hilbert axiomatic system in Pure utilizing only syntactic rules of substitution + MP (unlike provided example in https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/library/Pure/Pure-Examples/First_Order_Logic.html relying on mapping ⟶ to ⟹). The definition is:
theory Hilbert
imports
  Pure (* not HOL! *)
begin

typedecl hbool (* Hilbert boolean *)

judgment Trueprop :: ‹hbool ⇒ prop› ("_" 5)

axiomatization
  imp :: ‹hbool ⇒ hbool ⇒ hbool› (infixr ‹⟶› 25)
  where ax1: ‹A⟶(B⟶A)›
    and ax2: ‹(A⟶B⟶C)⟶(A⟶B)⟶(A⟶C)›
    and mp: ‹A ⟶ B ⟹ A ⟹ B›

in order to shorten proofs I want to introduce simple lemma, which is kind of "macros":
lemma impExtra: "A⟹(B⟶A)"

I learned that proof - syntax allows to work with proofs without any "magic" behind and proofs look like:
proof -
  assume ass1: "A"
  from ax1 have fact1:
    "A⟶B⟶A".
  from mp fact1 ass1 have fact2:
      "B⟶A".

After I've got fact2 + ass1 I don't know the syntax to get to the lemma statement - basically I don't know how to introduce Pure's  ⟹ syntax from assumption & current statement.
When I write:
  from ass1 fact2 show "A⟹(B⟶A)" .

I get:
Failed to apply initial proof method:
using this:
    A
    B ⟶ A
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. A ⟹ B ⟶ A

Is there a rule of Pure to introduce ⟹?
PS I'm able to prove the lemma using similar syntax (and use it as originally intended in other proofs):
lemma impX: assumes assA: A shows "B⟶A"
proof -
  from ax1 have fact1:
    "A⟶B⟶A".
  from mp fact1 assA show fact2:
      "B⟶A".
qed

lemma "X⟶A⟶A"
proof -
  from imp_truth have fact1:
    "A⟶A".
  from impX fact1 show
    "X⟶A⟶A".
qed

What is the difference between ⟹ and assumes? What parts do they belongs to - Isabelle/Pure/Isar?

Assumptions made by assume are discharged automatically whenever a fact depending on that assumption is used to prove a goal. So all you have to do is tell Isabelle to solve your goal with fact2, and it will automatically unify the A assumption behind fact2 with the A premise of the goal.
proof -
  assume ass1: A
  from ax1 have fact1: "A⟶B⟶A".
  from mp fact1 ass1 have fact2: "B⟶A".
  from fact2 show "A⟹(B⟶A)".
qed

Mind, you can eta-contract this proof to just
proof -
from mp ax1 show "A⟹(B⟶A)".
qed


So my problem was mentioning of assumption reference in from...
